# Hadoop Connection Timed Out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hadoop, ssh, redhat

I am creating a hadoop single node cluster. I am using RedHat on google cloud. I have already turned off the firewall rule for security. My Red Hat is E2-medium based on x86/64 architecture.

Hadoop Version (Due to work requirement, I have to use 2.9.2)

```
hadoop-2.9.2
```

Java Version I have no problem on setting the jdk settings.

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.20" 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1) (build 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.20.0.8-1) (build 11.0.20+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried to review the initialisation of hadoop namenode but it turns out that only namenode manager is turned on.

```
[hadoop@rootvm ~]$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [hadoop.tecadmin.com]
hadoop.tecadmin.com: ssh: connect to host hadoop.tecadmin.com port 22: Connection timed out
localhost: chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Operation not permitted
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
localhost: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:FlOH6JIX6jQuQe0+SJP6ovh6ZFYCmRFK4zMxyz1aOx8.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:1: localhost
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts:4: 10.XXX.0.2
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
0.0.0.0: Warning: Permanently added '0.0.0.0' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
0.0.0.0: chown: changing ownership of '/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Operation not permitted
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open '/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out' for reading: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-cuhk-ssh-e2.asia-east2-a.c.root.internal.out: Permission denied
```

I expect I can create hadoop single node cluster.

Comment: Why not use GCP Dataproc?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your data under `/usr/local/hadoop` you need to change the ownership of this directory to the user you want to run hadoop  (seems like it is `hadoop`). The command you can use is:

```
chown -R hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
```

and the above command need to be executed as `root` user.